# Select all rows that have no children

Tags: mysql

I'm really having a brain-fail on this one.

I have the following table:

```
id    parentID     name
1     0            Frank
2     1            Sally
3     1            John
4     3            Beth
```

I'd like a statement that selects only those items that have no children, so in the previous example:

```
Sally
Beth
```

Would be the result. Can't seem to figure out a query to do this without creating a recursive function, which I don't want do to if I can avoid.

Comment: How should I know a parent has no children?

Comment: What tells us that Sally and Beth have no children?

Comment: because there aren't records with parent either 2 or 4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select yt.name
    from YourTable yt
    where not exists (select null from YourTable where parentID = yt.id)
```

Although less efficient (see: [Left outer join vs NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)), you could also do this with a left join:

```
select yt1.name
    from YourTable yt1
        left join YourTable yt2
            on yt1.id = yt2.parentID
    where yt2.id is null
```

Comment: Please note the referenced blog post is for Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. The conclusions it draws may not be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

```
select t.name
from that_table t
where t.id not in (select parentID from that_table);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select person.ID, person.name
FROM table AS person
LEFT OUTER JOIN table AS child ON person.ID = child.parentID
WHERE child.parentID IS NULL
```

or in less efficient form

```
select person.ID, person.name, count(child.id) AS number_of_children
FROM table AS person
LEFT JOIN table AS child on person.ID = child.parentID
GROUP BY person.id
HAVING number_of_children = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, 
    (SELECT count(c.id) FROM yourtable AS c WHERE c.parent_id=p.id) AS childs
    FROM yourtable AS p 
        WHERE 1
HAVING childs = 0
```